# apt update error "no route to host" on ubuntu servers

Tags: apt, wireless, 20.04

This morning I ran `sudo apt update` and, I got following error (many times):
[image: apt no route to host error]

I think it is able to connect with some repos. I tried pinging `43.255.166.254` which showed 100% packet loss. I also tried running 'Software Updater' which just basically told me to "Please check your internet connection".

I have checked my connection and verified that internet is working---chrome and firefox has no issue whatsoever.

Comment: in.archive.ubuntu.com is **not** a Ubuntu server, but a mirror available for users.  If you're not happy with that mirror, select another one in your country (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)  or use the Canonical/Ubuntu servers.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the clarification. I switched to another mirror and it worked.